# Run local npm package on windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, path, npm

I was reading the following lines on a karma tutorial:

- Install karma with `npm install karma -D`
- Create the karma config by running `karma init`

Running `karma init` does not work (at least in windows) because the installed package isn't added to the PATH variable.

Is there a way to configure a "local" path or I have to call karma explicitly with node using `node node_modules/karma/bin/karma init` instead?

Thanks

Comment: I think -D should be -g which means install globaly. This will add karma to path.

Comment: Thanks, if you post it as an answer i'll mark it as correct

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use **-g** switch to install it globaly

```
npm install karma -g
```